# The wishing lever - what are the blue drops on ground?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I found a magic penny. then pull the lever and a 3x3 of blue drops appears on the ground - walking over them pops them like bubbles, but I notice no other effect. What is this about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of the drops works like the 4th spell in the Psionics skill, restoring 4 hp.

[Source](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2330356)